# Program returning undefined variable (python)

Tags: python-3.x, variables, undefined

trying to get the following code to work, it still returns that the variable is undefined when the user enters an integer to try and assign a gender. How would you fix this?

```
#define the function for the physical characteristics question
def physical_characteristics_question (question, answer1, answer2, answer3) :
    print (question)
    print ('1. ' + answer1)
    print ('2. ' + answer2)
    print ('3. ' + answer3)

    while True:
        variable = (input('Please enter a number: '))
        while True:
        #repeats question if a type other than integer is entered
            try:
                int(variable)
                break
            except ValueError:
                variable = 0
                continue

        #repeats question if a number out of range is entered
        if int(variable) >= 1 and int(variable) <= 3:
            break

    return int(variable)


physical_characteristics_question ("What is your gender?", 'male', 'female', 'other')

if (variable) == 1:
    gender = 'male'
elif (variable) == 2:
    gender = 'female'
else:
    gender = 'other'
```

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: You didn’t assign the return value to anything; do `variable = physical_characteristics_question("What is your gender?", …)`. Variables you assign to in a function are only available in that function.

Comment: Fixed, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `physical_characteriscs_question` isn't returning its results to any variable. Try doing this:

```
variable = physical_characteristics_question ("What is your gender?", 'male', 'female', 'other')
```